# How does return work in Javascript without a function being invoked?

Tags: javascript, return, call

I'm studying from this [site](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions) and came upon this question and answer:

> Write a sum method which will work properly when invoked using either
>   syntax below.

```
console.log(sum(2,3));   // Outputs 5  
console.log(sum(2)(3));  // Outputs 5
```

//answer

```
function sum(x) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
  } else {
    return function(y) { return x + y; };
  }
}
```

I understand the code in the if statement, but not in the else statement because it's simply returning a function. That function isn't called with a '()', so given the 2nd scenario of `console.log(sum(2)(3));` I don't see why it will return 5. I can only see that it will return `function(3) {return 2 + 3}` which should throw an error.

Comment: *"...That function isn't called with a '()'..."* It is being called with `()`. It just happens to be after the first `()`. `sum(2)(3)` The `(2)` invokes `sum`, and the `(3)` invokes whatever was returned from `sum(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The else statement is returning a function with the x value encapsulated from the first call**

To explain it will break it down a little

```
var fresult = sum(3);

// right now fresult is a function that will add 3 
// to the variable you call fresult with
// basically function(y){ return 3 + y; }
var result = fresult(4);

//result is 7 
console.log(result);
```

Think of it like the **value of x** is being **captured by the function** that is being returned, which you can then call

**This encapsulation is created by the closure created in the anonymous function in the else's return statement**

To learn more about closures take a look at [this MDN Article about them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), they will be able to explain it a lot better than I could.

They actually have an example that is very similar to yours, where they try to explain the concept as being similar to a factory:

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

Article Says :

> In this example, we have defined a function makeAdder(x) which takes a
>   single argument x and returns a new function. The function it returns
>   takes a single argument y, and returns the sum of x and y.
>
> In essence, makeAdder is a function factory — it creates functions
>   which can add a specific value to their argument. In the above example
>   we use our function factory to create two new functions — one that
>   adds 5 to its argument, and one that adds 10.
>
> add5 and add10 are both closures. They share the same function body
>   definition, but store different environments. In add5's environment, x
>   is 5. As far as add10 is concerned, x is 10.

So if you are used to a more traditional programming language some use cases that you would have for private variables would be the same as capturing variables value's in a closure

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(2) = function (y){ return 2 + y }
```

You are calling that function with `(3)`

Answer (score 2):

You can store a function in a variable.

Basic idea is

```
var foo = function(y) {
    return y
};
```

So when we look at

```
console.log(sum(2)(3));
```

can be written as

```
var part1 = sum(2);  //aka part1 = function(y) { return 2 + y; };
var ans = part1(3);
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: good day sir, I am new to JS and was doing my research on how return works behind the scenes. Can I imagine it like this, say, we have code like var num = function(){return 5} Is it true that when we return 5 then 5 behind the scenes Replaces function expression?

Answer (score 1):

`else` part is an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) that accepts `one` argument.

In case `sum(2)(3)`

It goes into else loop, where `x = 2` since its called as `sum(2)`, whereas `(3)` is an anonymous function with no name.

hence,

```
return function(y) { return x + y; };
```

becomes

```
return function(3) { return 2 + 3; };
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a bit different from many languages. Functions can be passed around as variables. In your case, what's happening is much easier to see when broken down into the steps that actually occur.

First, since `sum(2)` has only one parameter, we go to the `else` block, which you already know. What's happening there is that we are returning a function, substituting `x` for the variable that was passed into `sum(x)`. So basically, what's being returned is a function that returns `2 + y`. This is what it would look like if we wanted to write it out on its own:

```
function(y) {
    return 2 + y;
}
```

The second set of parenthesis in `sum(2)(3)` is basically saying "call the function that was returned by `sum(2)` and send it the parameter `3`.

Here's basically an expanded version of the whole operation:

```
function sum(x) {
    if (arguments.length == 2) {
        return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
    } else {
        return function(y) { return x + y; };
    }
}

var addTwo = sum(2);

console.log(addTwo(3));
```

The short version basically just skips creating a separate variable for the result of `sum(2)` and just immediately calls the new function instead.